# Docfx not recognice class c#

Tags: c#, docfx

I have the following background service C# project directory that I want to document with Docfx.

[image: Directories]

Currently it documents the Worker.cs class, the classes that are in the "Objects" folder that are objects and the classes that are in the "Configuration" folder, specifically ConfigurationHelper which is an object of the xml file and IConfigurationHelper which is the interface.

The main problem with Docfx is that it does not recognize some of my c# classes which are the one in the "Functions" folder of which Utils.cs are my functions and also the Program.cs class, all these classes are ignored by Docfx.

[image: Files not detect Docfx]

I have a class called Program.cs that is in the same folder, but docfx doesn't recognize it.

This is my docfx.json file configuration

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "**/TestSharp.csproj",
            "**/Program.cs"
          ],
          "exclude": [
            "**/bin/**",
            "**/obj/**"
          ],
          "cwd": ".."
        }
      ],
      "dest": "obj/api"
    }
  ],
  "build": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.{md,yml}"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "output": "_site",
    "template": [
      "default",
      "modern"
    ],
    "globalMetadata": {
      "_appName": "mysite",
      "_appTitle": "mysite",
      "_enableSearch": true,
      "pdf": true
    }
  },
  "metadataOptions": {
    "swagger": {
      "source": [
        {
          "files": [
            "**/TestSharp.csproj"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dest": "swagger"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Program.cs

```
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

/// <summary>
/// Main class of the application.
/// </summary>
public class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point of the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Command line arguments.</param>
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string basedir = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Logs"); // Base directory for log files

        LoggerConfiguration(basedir);

        IConfigurationRoot _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json"))
            .Build();

        IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<TestSharp.Worker>(); // Add hosted service
                services.AddSingleton<TestSharp.Configuration.ConfigurationHelper, TestSharp.Configuration.ConfigurationHelper>();
                services.AddLogging(builder =>
                {
                    builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning); // Set minimum log level to Warning
                    builder.AddConsole(); // Log to console
                });
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures Serilog logger.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="basedir">Base directory for log files.</param>
    private static void LoggerConfiguration(string basedir) => Serilog.Log.Logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug() // Set minimum log level to Debug
        .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}") // Write to console
        .WriteTo.File($"{basedir}\\a2m2logger.txt", rollingInterval: Serilog.RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileTimeLimit: new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0)) // Write to file
        .CreateLogger();
}
```

This is my Utils.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Query.Models;
using Serilog;
using SFTPHelper;
using SharedVariables;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using WatchDog.Configuration;
using WatchDog.Objects.JsonReport;
using WatchDog.Objects.StatusCompanies;
using WatchDog.Objects.StatusData;
using WatchDog.Objects.StatusSqlLite;

public class Utils
{

    Timer timer;
    private int _seconds;
    private string _dateTimmer;






/// <summary>
/// Starts and configures a timer, getting the current time.
/// </summary>
private void StartTimer()
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz");
    timer = new Timer(state => UpdateTimer(date), null, 0, 1000);
}

/// <summary>
/// Updates the timer and displays information on the console.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dateTimer">Original date and time of the timer.</param>
private void UpdateTimer(string dateTimer)
{
    _seconds++;

    int hours = _seconds / 3600;
    int minutes = (_seconds % 3600) / 60;
    int remainingSeconds = _seconds % 60;

    _dateTimer = $"{hours:D2}:{minutes:D2}:{remainingSeconds:D2}";

    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
    Console.Write($"{dateTimer} [TMR] {hours:D2}:{minutes:D2}:{remainingSeconds:D2}");
}

/// <summary>
/// Stops the timer and releases associated resources.
/// </summary>
private void StopTimer()
{
    timer.Dispose();
    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
}

/// <summary>
/// Displays and writes the content of the LOG according to the process.
/// <remarks>
/// Allows modifying the importance type of the LOG content, whether it is information, warning, or error.
/// </remarks>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Description text.</param>
/// <param name="process">Process name.</param>
/// <param name="type">Importance type.</param>
public void LogOut(string text, string process, int type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case 0:
            Log.Information($"[{process}] {text}");
            break;
        case 1:
            Log.Warning($"[{process}] {text}");
            break;
        case 2:
            Log.Error($"[{process}] {text}");
            break;
    }
}



}
```

I would like to know why Docfx does not take these files or if it is a configuration problem with the docfx.json file. I need Docfx to read Utils.cs and Program.cs comments.

Comment: "*What is the error?*" - You are supposed to provide us with the error - [ask]

Comment: The `files` part in a metadata source isn't supposed to list *source* files, but projects. Is Program.cs not part of any project?

Comment: @JonSkeet Program.cs if it is part of the project, it is a class file that starts Worker.cs that occupies my service project in the background, it is in the same folder as the .csproj solution, but it is part of the project.

Comment: @Nautilus: Sorry, that comment was really unclear so I don't understand it - but fundamentally you can't include source files there, only project files. So if it's already included in a project covered  by `**/*.csproj` then you shouldn't need to do anything, and if it's not then you need to specify a project file that *does* include it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand and if I want it to read other .cs source code files, how should it be?

Comment: You would include those in a project, and specify the project in the docfx config.

Comment: @JonSkeet The idea of ​​using Docfx is that you pass the project path to this one and it should read all the files with comments, the problem is that there are .cs classes with comments that Docfx does not consider and having to put another project I find complex, That's why I ask about how the configuration of the json file should be.

Comment: "the problem is that there are .cs classes with comments that Docfx does not consider" - if they're already in a project which docfx is loading, then that's an entirely different problem and you should provide a [mcve] of that. Trying to specify the .cs file in the configuration is *not* the solution to that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edit the question for better understanding.

Comment: That isn't a [mcve] though. We've no idea what's in Program.cs, aside from anything else. As an example of what I'd want to see, you might refer to https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/8629 - it's got the config and the source file (both *minimal*) in the issue, so it's easy to reproduce. There's no project file in that case - but in *this* case, you might want to include that.